# Changes done in external html page are not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I had made a change in an external html page which is then loaded in an angular component but when I refreshed the angular app the changed did not showed up immediately.But after a day when I loaded the page the changed I made showed up.
what could be the possible reason ?

**Note** : The application is been running on the server for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to the cache issue depends on the browser try clearing the cache manually of the browser and then try to refresh. for chrome press ctrl+F5 to refresh the page.